# How to: power analysis with log-normal distributed data

Tags: statistical-power, lognormal-distribution, gpower

Assuming the following data:

```
Group A   Group B
580       170    
206       1
1680      292
1300      426
520       22
1440      300
1020      2
1680      20
1120      5860
572       2
```

I want to do a power analysis based on Group A and also Group B to compute the required sample size necessary to see a 10-fold reduction (effect size), given alpha=0.05 and power of either 0.8 or 0.9.

Group A seems to satisfy the normality test (QQ plot). I therefore can calculate the mean, SD and calculate the *effect size d* as follows: `smallest difference between means /SD = 1012-101/521 = 1.75`. Plugging these values in G*Power gives me a total sample size of 16 (8 per group).

Q1) What about the group B? It's clearly not normally distributed, looks like a log-normal distribution. Should I compute geometric mean and geometric SD? If I do so, the effect size become very, very small, requiring >300 subjects. Maybe this is correct given the high scatter of the data.

Q2) What if the group of which I power the experiment (e.g., Group A) is normally distributed, but the intervention group is not? In other words, the distribution or the SD changes between the reference group and the outcome?

I hope this was clear enough, if not - happy to clarify.